# gdal_translate Radial NetCDF to GeoTIFF does not create georeferenced image

Tags: gdal, netcdf, gdal-translate

I have weather radar data inside of a radial-NetCDF file. The public link to the file in question is [here on my google drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BEzktDSSFI1ecVXnRXHOM-2wC1-0LpCf/view?usp=sharing) The variable name is "BaseReflectivityDR".

I would like to simply convert this file to geoTIF, and I did so with the following command :

```
gdal_translate NETCDF:"KCRP_H0Z_20210612_2054.nc":BaseReflectivityDR Output_FileName.tif
```

However, the output image is not correctly georeferenced.

I tried running another script on the output file to convert to 3857 (my end goal) but it seems to have done nothing except create a copy of the output TIFF. I admit that this is not my strongest area :

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -of Gtiff Output_FileName.tif Output_FileName-projected.tif
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : gdalinfo as per request is now below :

```
Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: KCRP_H0Z_20210612_2054.nc
Size is 1840, 720
Origin = (-124.875000000000000,235.000347705146027)
Pixel Size = (249.750000000000000,-0.000695410292072)
Metadata:
  azimuth#long_name=azimuth angle in degrees: 0 = true north, 90 = east
  azimuth#units=degrees
  azimuth#_CoordinateAxisType=RadialAzimuth
  BaseReflectivityDR#long_name=HighResolution: Base Reflectivity
  BaseReflectivityDR#units=dBz
  BaseReflectivityDR#_CoordinateAxes=elevation azimuth gate rays_time latitude longitude altitude
  gate#long_name=Radial distance to the start of gate
  gate#units=meters
  gate#_CoordinateAxisType=RadialDistance
  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=RADIAL
  NC_GLOBAL#conventions=_Coordinates
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_name=NOAA/NWS
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_url=http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/radar/radarproducts.html
  NC_GLOBAL#data_max=62
  NC_GLOBAL#data_min=0
  NC_GLOBAL#DateCreated=2021-06-12T20:56:14Z
  NC_GLOBAL#Divider=-1
  NC_GLOBAL#ElevationNumber=1
  NC_GLOBAL#format=Level3/NIDS
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=29.84918
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=25.718819
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=-99.847618
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=-95.174385
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_vertical_max=43.281601
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_vertical_min=43.281601
  NC_GLOBAL#isRadial=1
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=WSR-88D; NIDS
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=N0Q
  NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority=NOAA/NCDC
  NC_GLOBAL#NumberOfMaps=0
  NC_GLOBAL#OperationalMode=1
  NC_GLOBAL#ProductStation=CRP
  NC_GLOBAL#ProductStationName=Corpus Christi/Corpus Christ,TX,US
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarAltitude=43.2816
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarElevationNumber=5
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarLatitude=27.784
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarLongitude=-97.511
  NC_GLOBAL#SequenceNumber=101
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=Nexrad level 3 data are WSR-88D radar products.N0Q is a radial image of base reflectivity field and its range 248 nm
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2021-06-12T20:54:46Z
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=2021-06-12T20:54:46Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Nexrad Level 3 Data
  NC_GLOBAL#VolumeCoveragePatternName=35
  NC_GLOBAL#VolumeScanNumber=4
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    -124.875,     235.000)
Lower Left  (    -124.875,     234.500)
Upper Right (  459415.125,     235.000)
Lower Right (  459415.125,     234.500)
Center      (  229645.125,     234.750)
Band 1 Block=1840x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.96920996838686905e+36
  Unit Type: dBz
  Metadata:
    long_name=HighResolution: Base Reflectivity
    NETCDF_VARNAME=BaseReflectivityDR
    units=dBz
    _CoordinateAxes=elevation azimuth gate rays_time latitude longitude altitude
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the input image appears to appears to be just points, not a georeferenced image. You will need to find a way to resample those points to a georeferenced grid first and then export to a raster.

Comment: You are right that -a_srs does nothing for the data. It is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-a_srs `No reprojection is done`. With that parameter you can set the srs if it is unknown, or if it is originally wrong. It affects only file metadata. What does `gdalinfo NETCDF:"KCRP_H0Z_20210612_2054.nc":BaseReflectivityDR Output_FileName.tif` report as original coordinate system?

Comment: @user30184 I have added that information to my original post. As you can see, it's radial data, but maybe GDAL does not have a way to convert this without more information. Weather data gets complicated.

Comment: It may be that the Proj library and GDAL cannot handle this kind of coordinate system. Write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask.